# WFFM Hide introduction

Tags: wffm

I have set up a WFFM enquiry form on my website, which works fine.

*But what I wanted to do is to hide the form "**Introduction**" block, when it is submitted.*

Is there an out-of-the-box way to do that?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to achieve?

Comment: So, when somebody submits a form, the success message is shown, but I want to hide the form introduction message which might be confusing/irrelevant when there is a success text

Comment: Might be better to use a success page instead.. would that be a solution?

Comment: @Gatogordo I have done that as a workaround, but the above requirement is still pending from client :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in a fresh sitecore 8.1 Update-3 instance using WFFM 8.1 Update-3 and the introduction block is getting hidden when I submit the form.

I just created a simple form with a basic HTML introduction:

[image]

This is how my form is rendered on the page before submitting it:

[image]

After the submission, the entire form component is replaced by the success message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get around the bug. I would just use a jQuery show/hide function. You should be able to get the name or id of the field once it is rendered and plug that in your function.

Something like this on document.ready or submit. You might have to target it a little different, but I know show hide works with WFFM since I have had hidden fields before on the forms.

$(".wffmfield").hide();

$(".wffmfield").show();